# ESXi 6: Could not start VMX: msg.vmk.status.VMK_NOT_FOUND

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can help me out with this, as I have no idea what to do.

I was configuring WSUS, and was just about to click finish on the configuration wizard when the VM completely hung. I don't know why, it's never done anything like this before. The VM is running Server 2012 R2 that is a DNS server, DHCP server, primary and only (yes, I know that's bad) domain controller, file server, backup server, etc. for my home environment.

I know it's bad to have all this in one VM, but it was migrated from a single server that at the time was all I had. I'm currently working on splitting the services and roles up into separate VMs, but that's not what this is about.

The VM completely froze up. I couldn't even ping it any more. I forced a shutdown of the VM, and tried to start it again. I then received the error that I've attached as a screenshot.

I shutdown my other VMs and restarted the ESXi host. The same thing as before happened when I tried to start the VM.

I've attached a screenshot of the error.

I'm also happy to provide the logs if that would help.

TLDR: Windows Server as a VM completely hung, forced shutdown of VM from vSphere Client, attempted to start VM, received error, rebooted ESXi host, attempted to start VM, received error. Error is attached as image.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3torm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new VM and mounted the VMDKs from the failed VM. This fixed my issue and everything is working as usual now.